# Display particular woocommerce subcategory as a list with no space

Tags: css, list, woocommerce, hook, categories

main category slug name is car-battery. I want to display all sub categories of it as a list when click on it.

I have tried css code

```
.product-loop-categories .product-category a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.product-loop-categories .product-category a img {
    display: none;
}
```

This code displays all categories as a list. I want to achieve only for one main category. How to do it

Comment: You can customize the query. Return dataset only based on your condition.